# read user defined data fields android contacts

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts

I'm trying to read the fields which I added with google contacts to my contacts.
I know that these fields get synced, because i can see it with an alternative contact viewer app. ->Contact View by SoftWyer
How could i query this data?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
String selection = ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?" ;
String[] selectionParams = new String[]    
  {"vnd.com.google.cursor.item/contact_user_defined_field"};

Cursor tokenCur = cr.query(
ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
null,
selection ,
selectionParams ,
null);
```